Unable to recreate an S3 bucket in AWS with same name
I created a bucket with name abcd in AWS S3 in stockholm region and immediately deleted it from there.Afterwards when, i trying to recreate the bucket with same name i.e abcd in mumbai region aws is not allowing me to create it as seen in the screenshot.

I have been waited for past 1 hour and tried again but getting the same error.
I created a new account and created the same bucket name there as well i am getting the same issue.


https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html

When you delete a bucket, there may be a delay of up to one hour before the bucket name is available for reuse in a new region or by a new bucket owner. If you re-create the bucket in the same region or with the same bucket owner, there is no delay.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUSYkbtoqFS3mEjDVWsy-cEw/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-bucket-and-create-again-the-bucket-on-a-different-region-with-same-name

When you delete a bucket, there is indeed a propagation delay before the bucket name becomes available for reuse. This delay can vary and is not precisely defined by AWS, but it typically ranges from a few minutes to several hours

